# Activity log/history on list in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

Is there possible to view `activity log/history` from a `list` in SharePoint? Not the versioning on an item but I want to see all the `activities on the list`.

Or do I need to do a custom action for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by enabling audit logs. Check this article:
http://sharepoint-works.blogspot.de/2013/07/audit-logging-in-sharepoint-2013.html

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to specify a specific list? We have a lot of data that would be logged (many documents being deleted/edited etc).

Comment: Yes of course, there is already a related post in stackexchange: [link](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/146114/how-to-audit-one-specific-list-library)