# Generate Change/Audit log for a specific SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list

I am new to SharePoint and unable to find a solution on Google. I want to be able to track changes done to any item on the SharePoint list. I have tried the audit log reports available but I am not able to restrict the output of that audit report to a specific list. Also there is no "Restrict this report to" option under custom report section (as stated in a couple of google responses).

Use case: if any authorised user makes a change on any item in the SharePoint list, I should be able to extract an audit report to see what was the change made and when.

Would really appreciate your support on this.

Regards,

Robin

Answer (score 1):

Three options:

Turn on Version History in the list settings. Then you can open each list items version history and see who changed what and when. This data is not easy to access for analysis or reporting, though, unless you are prepared to write code and access the REST API.

You can also create a Power Automate flow that runs whenever an item is modified in that list. You can use the workflow to create new items in a log list, but the workflow will not be able to determine which column(s) of the item were changed and which were not.

You can use a hack to export the version history to Excel, but it is clunky. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10561661/sharepoint-list-version-history-export-to-excel

Answer (score 0):

**Please refer to the following steps to audit one specific list/library in SharePoint Online:**

Go to the specific list/library >> **List settings** >> I**nformation Management Policy Settings**, clicked on "**item**" >> selecte "**Enable Auditing**" option and then selected events >> **OK**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Thanks alot for this valuable response. I was able to enable this for the list. The next challenge was to execute the audit report for 1 specific sharepoint list , which I am unable to do still as I cannot see any "Restrict Report To" option under the Custom Report option. So unable to restrict the audit report to 1 specific list.

Comment: From the info provided here -> https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/146114/94427 I couldnt create a policy for the list I want to execute the audit report for. I guess it might be due to access restrictions.

Appreciate all support on this.

Comment: Hi, Bobin. Thanks for you shareing. This is very helpful. Have a nice day!